# Not able to install any piece of SQL server 2012 dev edition on my windows 7

Tags: sql-server-2012, installation

I have tried everything i can think f to install SQL 2012 but no luck I am getting these errors but after looking through the logs I can't find the actual cause to get a solution.

every feature gives me this error in the summary:

Detailed results:
Feature:                       Management Tools - Complete
Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
Reason for failure:            An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.
Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.

There is not information to resolve the error!

here is the last few lines from  detail.txt about the installation:

> (01) 2012-09-19 15:35:07 Slp: Condition is false because the required
>   feature SQL_SNAC_SDK_sqlncli_Cpu64 failed in result Result (01)
>   2012-09-19 15:35:07 Slp: Action
>   "ConfigEvent_SQL_PowerShell_Tools_ANS_sql_ssms_Cpu64_Install_Finalize_finalize"
>   will return false due to the following conditions: (01) 2012-09-19
>   15:35:07 Slp: Condition "Feature dependency condition for action:
>   ConfigEvent_SQL_PowerShell_Tools_ANS_sql_ssms_Cpu64_Install_Finalize_finalize
>   The condition tests feature: SQL_PowerShell_Tools_ANS_sql_ssms_Cpu64.
>   There are 2 dependant features. The feature is tested for results:
>   ValidateResult, Result, CleanupResult." did not pass as it returned
>   false and true was expected. (01) 2012-09-19 15:35:07 Slp: Condition
>   is false because the required feature SQL_SSMS_Adv_sql_ssms_Cpu64
>   failed in result Result (01) 2012-09-19 15:35:07 Slp: Action
>   "ConfigEvent_SQL_SSMS_Full_sql_tools_Cpu64_Install_Finalize_finalize"
>   will return false due to the following conditions: (01) 2012-09-19
>   15:35:07 Slp: Condition "Feature dependency condition for action:
>   ConfigEvent_SQL_SSMS_Full_sql_tools_Cpu64_Install_Finalize_finalize
>   The condition tests feature: SQL_SSMS_Full_sql_tools_Cpu64. There are
>   4 dependant features. The feature is tested for results:
>   ValidateResult, Result, CleanupResult." did not pass as it returned
>   false and true was expected. (01) 2012-09-19 15:35:07 Slp: Condition
>   is false because the required feature SQL_SSMS_Adv_sql_ssms_Cpu64
>   failed in result Result (01) 2012-09-19 15:35:07 Slp: Completed
>   Action: FinalizeTimingConfigAction, returned True (01) 2012-09-19
>   15:35:07 Slp:
>   ---------------------------------------------------------------------- (01) 2012-09-19 15:35:07 Slp: Running Action: CreateARPRegKeyAction
>   (01) 2012-09-19 15:35:07 Slp: Completed Action: CreateARPRegKeyAction,
>   returned True (01) 2012-09-19 15:35:07 Slp:
>   ---------------------------------------------------------------------- (01) 2012-09-19 15:35:07 Slp: Running Action:
>   RunRefreshDiscoveryAction (01) 2012-09-19 15:35:07 Slp: Running
>   discovery on local machine (01) 2012-09-19 15:35:08 Slp: Discovery on
>   local machine is complete (01) 2012-09-19 15:35:08 Slp: Completed
>   Action: RunRefreshDiscoveryAction, returned True (01) 2012-09-19
>   15:35:08 Slp:
>   ---------------------------------------------------------------------- (01) 2012-09-19 15:35:08 Slp: Running Action: NotifyProgressComplete
>   (01) 2012-09-19 15:35:08 Slp: Completed Action:
>   NotifyProgressComplete, returned True (01) 2012-09-19 15:35:08 Slp:
>   ---------------------------------------------------------------------- (01) 2012-09-19 15:35:08 Slp: Skipping Action:
>   DeleteUninstalledPatchRegistryAndCacheFolderAction (01) 2012-09-19
>   15:35:08 Slp: Action is being skipped due to the following
>   restrictions:  (01) 2012-09-19 15:35:08 Slp: Condition "Do any of the
>   specified features match the expected scenario Uninstall" did not pass
>   as it returned false and true was expected. (01) 2012-09-19 15:35:08
>   Slp: Completed Action: ExecuteExtendedTimingsWorkflow, returned True
>   (01) 2012-09-19 15:35:08 Slp:
>   ---------------------------------------------------------------------- (01) 2012-09-19 15:35:08 Slp: Running Action: DeleteUpdates (01)
>   2012-09-19 15:35:08 Slp: Deleting folder
>   'C:\Users\mkimonos\AppData\Local\Temp\SQL Server 2012'. (01)
>   2012-09-19 15:35:08 Slp: Sco: Directory
>   C:\Users\mkimonos\AppData\Local\Temp\SQL Server 2012 does not exist
>   (01) 2012-09-19 15:35:08 Slp: Completed Action: DeleteUpdates,
>   returned True (01) 2012-09-19 15:35:09 Slp:
>   ---------------------------------------------------------------------- (01) 2012-09-19 15:35:09 Slp: Running Action: ExecuteCloseWorkflow
>   (01) 2012-09-19 15:35:09 Slp: Workflow to execute: 'CLOSE' (01)
>   2012-09-19 15:35:09 Slp:
>   ---------------------------------------------------------------------- (01) 2012-09-19 15:35:09 Slp: Running Action:
>   DetermineProductFeatureSummary (01) 2012-09-19 15:35:09 Slp: Completed
>   Action: DetermineProductFeatureSummary, returned True (01) 2012-09-19
>   15:35:10 Slp:
>   ---------------------------------------------------------------------- (01) 2012-09-19 15:35:10 Slp: Running Action: ProduceStatusLogs (01)
>   2012-09-19 15:35:11 Slp: Completed Action: ProduceStatusLogs, returned
>   True (01) 2012-09-19 15:35:11 Slp:
>   ---------------------------------------------------------------------- (01) 2012-09-19 15:35:11 Slp: Running Action: FinalizeProgressStatus
>   (01) 2012-09-19 15:35:11 Slp: Completed Action:
>   FinalizeProgressStatus, returned True (01) 2012-09-19 15:35:11 Slp:
>   ---------------------------------------------------------------------- (01) 2012-09-19 15:35:11 Slp: Running Action: RebootMessageAction (01)
>   2012-09-19 15:35:11 Slp: Completed Action: RebootMessageAction,
>   returned True (01) 2012-09-19 15:35:11 Slp:
>   ---------------------------------------------------------------------- (01) 2012-09-19 15:35:11 Slp: Skipping Action: FinishPage (01)
>   2012-09-19 15:35:11 Slp: Action is being skipped due to the following
>   restrictions:  (01) 2012-09-19 15:35:11 Slp: Condition "Is the user's
>   scenario set to EditionUpgrade" did not pass as it returned false and
>   true was expected. (01) 2012-09-19 15:35:11 Slp:
>   ---------------------------------------------------------------------- (01) 2012-09-19 15:35:11 Slp: Running Action: CloseUI (01) 2012-09-19
>   15:35:11 Slp: Stop action skipped in UI Mode Full (01) 2012-09-19
>   15:35:11 Slp: Completed Action: CloseUI, returned True (01) 2012-09-19
>   15:35:12 Slp: Completed Action: ExecuteCloseWorkflow, returned True
>   (01) 2012-09-19 15:35:12 Slp: Completed Action:
>   ExecuteCompleteWorkflow, returned True (01) 2012-09-19 15:35:12 Slp:
>   Sco: Attempting to create base registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
>   machine  (01) 2012-09-19 15:35:12 Slp: Sco: Attempting to open
>   registry subkey Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\110 (01)
>   2012-09-19 15:35:12 Slp: Sco: Attempting to get registry value
>   CustomerFeedback (01) 2012-09-19 15:35:14 Slp:  (01) 2012-09-19
>   15:35:14 Slp:  (01) 2012-09-19 15:35:14 Slp:
>   ---------------------------------------------------------------------- (01) 2012-09-19 15:35:14 Slp:  (01) 2012-09-19 15:35:14 Slp: Error
>   result: -2068643839 (01) 2012-09-19 15:35:14 Slp: Result facility
>   code: 1203 (01) 2012-09-19 15:35:14 Slp: Result error code: 1 (01)
>   2012-09-19 15:35:14 Slp: Sco: Attempting to create base registry key
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, machine  (01) 2012-09-19 15:35:14 Slp: Sco:
>   Attempting to open registry subkey Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\110 (01) 2012-09-19 15:35:14 Slp: Sco: Attempting to get
>   registry value CustomerFeedback

Comment: Which version of win 7 and SQL 2012 are you using? Please include x86/64

Comment: Do you have any other instances of SQL Server on your machine?

Comment: Win 7 x64 PRo w/ SP 1 and the SQL is: en_sql_server_2012_developer_edition_x86_x64_dvd_813280.iso. AND YES I have SQL server Dev ed 2008 sp1 and

Comment: Can you verify that PowerShell is correctly installed on Windows and that you have also installed the .Net 3.5 framework?

Comment: How do i verify the Powershell is correctly installed? I know it's installed and it works because I use it each week to run  some scripts for  database build using PowerShell. and as far as i can see based on the folders in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64 and C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework 3.5 is installed. I am writing .net code in VS2010 in 4.0 as well.

Answer (score 13):

I had a similar isssue - Win7SP1, VS2010SP1, SQL2008R2, Powershell 2 etc. Every prerequisite was there and still SQL Server 2012 Developers edition did not install. Completing with the following error message for most of the features:

```
  Feature:                       Database Engine Services
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.
  Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
```

I did analysis on details.txt and figured that failure started with the following line:

```
Error: Action "Install_sqlncli_Cpu64_Action" failed during execution.
```

I figured it had something to do with "SQL Server 2012 Native Client". I think I had it installed with Azure SDK or something like this. So, I uninstalled it and re-ran SQL Server 2012 installer and it completed successfully!

Hope this helps.

Comment: I had exactly the same problem when installing MSDN iso on Azure VM. I tried installing ISOs for SQL 2012 as well 2k14 both resulted in error. Finally i removed this "SQL Server 2012 Native Client" via appwiz.cpl and SQL 2k14 installation went fine without error... :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd follow the following MSDN blog instructions: [How to Fix a failed SQL 2005, 2008, R2 or 2012 Install/Upgrade - MSSQLSERVER.INACTIVE](https://web.archive.org/web/20160216062237/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/baliles/archive/2012/04/27/how-to-fix-a-failed-sql-2005-2008-r2-or-2012-install-upgrade-mssqlserver-inactive.aspx). It saved my burning arse a few times.

Mainly, what you need to do is (can't quote correctly such a big text):

Start quote:

The REAL Resolution Steps: (don't bother trying to figure out what went wrong...feel free to try the most-recommended resolution first if you'd like...but I'd suggest that if you have the above error/result, do the following:

- Search your machine for files called Datastore_Discovery.xml (depending on how much you've got or done, you might see many of these...just open the most recent one and you'll be fine
- Open Datastore_Discovery.xml in an editor...given the formatting, what worked for me was in Visual Studio 2008/2010 and clicking Edit, Advanced, Format Document (this arranges the XML nicely)
- What you're looking for is all places where MSSQLServer.Inactive exists in the document as the Instance ID...below is a sample of how the line starts:
- < Instance Urn="Machine[@ID='IWE']/Product[@ID='SQLVNEXT']/Instance[@ID='MSSQLSERVER.INACTIVE']" ID="MSSQLSERVER.INACTIVE"
- Name="MSSQLSERVER.INACTIVE" ........
- Scroll along the lines around the above one and find the following value field: ProductCode="{9FFAE13C-6160-4DD0-A67A-DAC5994F81BD}" (and of course, don't ACTUALLY use the code you see here...yours will be different...look for the brackets and use yours :-) )
- There might be multiple ProductCodes, depending on how many times the  line lists MSSQLServer.Inactive, so make sure to find all ProductCodes...BUT BE CAREFUL that you ignore any VALID instances of SQL. Only look for the ones under MSSQLServer.Inactive entries.
- Now open a command line - For each of the ProductCodes that you found for the Inactive SQL Instances, type the following:
- msiexec /x {9FFAE13C-6160-4DD0-A67A-DAC5994F81BD}
- Do this for each Product Code that relates to an Inactive Instance
- Once complete, go back to your SQL installation media and run Setup
- Once the main splash screen launches, click on Tools, then Installed SQL Server features discovery report
- This will launch a web page listing the SQL Instances and all features per instance
- If you still see any MSSQLSERVER.INACTIVE there, you missed one of the ProductCodes and you need to double check. Otherwise, all of the orphaned SQL Instances should now be gone, and you can either Add Features or do a clean Default Instance reinstall

End quote.

This is what I did a few times to fix a corrupted installation and it worked flawlessly. I reinstalled only Reporting Services this way and so I didn't disable or deactivate the complete instance. A packaging engineer told me it's a usual stuff one should do to fix a corrupted application installation (remove corrupted components), but I admit I didn't know how to do that for each separate component of the SQL Server. Hopefully this will give you a hint and will work for you too.

Answer (score 0):

The answer isn't great but after multiple tries over a period of time i found nothing worked but when Microsoft released  SQL 2012 with sp1 in our MSDN subscription I tried that Install and it work!