# Remove sql server service from windows 7

Tags: sql-server-2005, windows

I had installed and later uninstalled SQL Server 2005 . I used registry cleaner tools and deleted all files related to SQL Server . 
Still the services console shows entry for previous installed database instance name .
Services management console I get this entry in Description column.
*`Failed to Read Description Error code 2`*

How to delete them otherwise new installtion is showing problem.

Comment: Try to fix the installation following the steps from [my answer](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/28634/418) to this [older problem](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/24563/not-able-to-install-any-piece-of-sql-server-2012-dev-edition-on-my-windows-7). Let us know if it works, please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the crude way is to run regedit as admin, go down to

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services

and remove the service entry from registry and reboot...

Or perhaps use the sysinternals process explorer tool to do the same thing....